# how to serializee/deserialize in specific format

Tags: java, .net, xml, serialization

I have an xml serialized version of object graph and want to understand which way it was serialized so that I can add similar thing with compatible format. I don't know which library/options allow this format

```
    public class MyRoot{
        public List<MyMember> members {get;set;}
        public List<Foo> foos {get;set;}
        public List<Bar> bars {get;set;}
    }
```

the xml I need to get is

```
<MyRoot>
 <members>...</members>
 <members>...</members>
 <members>...</members>

 <foos>...</foos>
 <foos>...</foos>
 <foos>...</foos>
 <foos>...</foos>

 <bars>...</bars>
 <bars>...</bars>
 <bars>...</bars>
 <bars>...</bars>
</MyRoot>
```

Comment: All you should need to do is apply annotations and the serializer will handle the rest.  See: XMLRootElement and XMLElement in javax.xml.bind.annotation.

Comment: yes or use [Jackson](https://stackabuse.com/serialize-and-deserialize-xml-in-java-with-jackson/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what Ryan and Jackson are suggesting. Tried out what Ryan suggested.

**MyRoot Class:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "MyRoot")
public class MyRoot {
    private List<MyMember> members;
    private List<Foo> foos;
    private List<Bar> bars;

    @XmlElement(name = "members")
    public List<MyMember> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    public void setMembers(List<MyMember> members) {
        this.members = members;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "foos")
    public List<Foo> getFoos() {
        return foos;
    }

    public void setFoos(List<Foo> foos) {
        this.foos = foos;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "bars")
    public List<Bar> getBars() {
        return bars;
    }

    public void setBars(List<Bar> bars) {
        this.bars = bars;
    }
}
```

**Foo Class**, **Bar class** and **MyMember Class** are identical in code:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Foo {
    private String content;

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

**Test Class with Main Method:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setContent("bar");
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setContent("");
        MyMember mymember = new MyMember();
        mymember.setContent("mymember");
        
        MyRoot root = new MyRoot();
        root.setBars(Arrays.asList(new Bar(), bar));
        root.setFoos(Arrays.asList(foo));
        root.setMembers(Arrays.asList(mymember));

        File file = new File("root.xml");
        JAXB.marshal(root, file);
    }
}
```

If you use Eclipse, refresh Explorer with F5 to see the new file **root.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MyRoot>
    <bars/>
    <bars>
        <content>bar</content>
    </bars>
    <foos>
        <content></content>
    </foos>
    <members>
        <content>mymember</content>
    </members>
</MyRoot>
```